# Application error after push to Heroku

Tags: heroku

I'm new to this and I've Googled this problem and nothing has helped. Can someone explain to me what the error is? I've tried to do the git add, commit then pushing to heroku again and that stuff.

```
2014-08-02T00:19:10.428030+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=practice-pinteresting.herokuapp.com request_id=24c5ed75-ab66-4898-bb58-eaf24ffbefce fwd="98.113.185.141" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-08-02T00:19:18.838612+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=practice-pinteresting.herokuapp.com request_id=9c7ca0d0-cfb3-4744-afed-be703a5b1d2e fwd="98.113.185.141" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-08-02T00:19:20.835561+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=practice-pinteresting.herokuapp.com request_id=bf617e64-6239-4ace-87ec-eef119aef160 fwd="98.113.185.141" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-08-02T00:19:24.217825+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=practice-pinteresting.herokuapp.com request_id=d767da81-9330-472c-aaa4-a53c06c4e303 fwd="98.113.185.141" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-08-02T00:19:28.047936+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=practice-pinteresting.herokuapp.com request_id=cab55122-63b5-42f6-b444-8cd0537246eb fwd="98.113.185.141" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-08-02T00:19:30.317759+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=practice-pinteresting.herokuapp.com request_id=79743c93-d65e-435a-8aec-39c87093e475 fwd="98.113.185.141" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: have you created a root page for your heroku app yet?

Comment: yes... i've put different gems and bundle installed them already... i've ran the migrations aswell... and i dont think that has anything to do with deployment either...

Comment: could youpost your config.rb file?

Comment: https://github.com/Liangalvin/pinteresting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O.k. figured it out.  The "ends" in your pins_controller.rb were messed up. If you remove the end at line 52 (yes the very last one) and at line 40 it should work, it did for me I am looking at your app right now.

Just so you know I figured it out by using

```
 heroku run rails c
```

sometimes that gives you more useful info, in this case it pointed to your controller and told me about the syntax erros.

if you want to copy and paste this code should work below, it does for me, and please do not forget to click the check mark if this solves you issue.

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

   def index
     @pins = Pin.all
    end

   def show
   end

   def new
    @pin = Pin.new
   end

   def edit
   end

  def create
    @pin = Pin.new(pin_params)

    if @pin.save
      redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully created.' 
     else
    render :new 
  end
end

 def update
     if @pin.update(pin_params)
       redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully updated.'
     else
      render :edit 
    end
  end
end

 def destroy
   @pin.destroy
    redirect_to pins_url
 end

  private
     #Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_pin
    @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
   end

   # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
   def pin_params
     params.require(:pin).permit(:description)
   end
```